# ggboxplot - How can I inrease distance between adjacent boxplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am using the ggpubr package to do boxplots with ggboxplot. Any suggestions on how to increase the distance between the adjacent boxplots?

I have been using R for a couple of weeks and I am aware that my script might be written better.

My code:

```
flowdata <- read.csv("flowdata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

flowdata$Haplotype = factor(flowdata$Haplotype,levels(flowdata$Haplotype)
[c(5,1,2,3,4,6)])

library(ggpubr)

p<-ggboxplot(flowdata, x="TP", y="Treg",  add = "jitter",width = 0.5, shape 
= "Treatment", fill = "Haplotype", palette = c("#0092d1","#62b232","#b23a32","#b232a3","#99cccc","#132a64"))+scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,23))

p1<-p+theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size=8), text = element_text(family = "Calibri"), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+ labs(x = expression(paste("")),
y = expression(paste(CD4^+{}, CD25^+{}, "cells/µL")))
p1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parameter 'width' specifies the width of the boxes, so a simple solution would be to reduce that value (from 0.5). This would not increase spacing of the boxes, but increase spacing *between* them and therefore make the boxes narrower.

However, it seems to me like your boxplots are well spaced, but your points (jitter) are overlapping, making the graph look messy. A simpler solution would be to remove them, or change them to points instead of jitter. Alternatively you could use a violin plot.

For finer control, 'standard' ggplot2 can be used, perhaps with cowplot which can give you formatting:

```
p <- ggplot(data = flowdata, mapping = aes(x = TP, y = Treg, fill = Haplotype)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(shape = Treatment)) +
  scale_shape_manual(c(21, 23)) + 
 scale_fill_manual(c("#0092d1","#62b232","#b23a32","#b232a3","#99cccc","#132a64")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text = element_text(size=8), text = element_text(family = "Calibri"), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  labs(x = expression(paste("")), y = expression(paste(CD4^+{}, CD25^+{}, "cells/µL")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Adams answer, I would furthermore suggest you get the boxplots into several facets, so that the plot is actually readable. I suppose the haplotype might be the interesting facet. Also, you could reduce the `size` of the jitter points or get some transparency `alpha` so that they are less present, but with the facet the boxplots are larger already, so this might solve the problem of readability by itself.

```
p <- ggplot(flowdata, aes(x = TP, y = Treg)) +
            geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
            geom_jitter(aes(shape = Treatment), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.8) +
            facet_wrap(~Haplotype, ncol = 3) +
            scale_shape_manual(c(21, 23)) + 
            theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
                  legend.text = element_text(size=8), 
                  text = element_text(family = "Calibri"), 
                  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
            labs(x = "", 
                 y = expression(paste(CD4^+{}, CD25^+{}, "cells/µL")))
```